# Create an availability webtest using template, parameterfile and powershell | New-AzApplicationInsightsWebTest

Tags: json, azure, powershell

I would like to create a webtest if not exist. New-AzApplicationInsightsWebTest creates or updates an Application Insights web test definition. The JSON template file has variables/properties which has to be assigned from parameter file. Variables, and webtest configuration are written as follows:

```
"variables": {
    "pingTestName": "[concat('MyTest', toLower(parameters('appName')))]"
  }

 "Configuration": {
          "WebTest": "[concat('<WebTest   Name=\"',...............
```

How can I deploy the webtest if not exist?

```
New-AzApplicationInsightsWebTest -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $WebTestDefinition.variables.pingTestName -Location "West Europe" -Tag @{$WebTestDefinition.resources.tags} -Configuration ....
```

I get error as bellow:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Tag'. Cannot convert value "@{[concat('hidden-link:',.........
```

Comment: Are you trying to create webtest using **ARMtemplate** or by using **New-AzApplicationInsightsWebTest** cmdlet ?

Comment: If you are trying to create the web test using ARM template, then you have to use [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-7.1.0) PowerShell cmdlet to deploy template.

Comment: Based on the documentation of [New-AzApplicationInsightsWebTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.applicationinsights/new-azapplicationinsightswebtest?view=azps-7.1.0) cmdlet , we understood that none of the parameters need JSON as input.

Comment: I am deploying webtest using build by yml. Hence it needs to be generic. I'll try your option.

Comment: Any update on trying the option which I have shared you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around this: Since I wanted a generic implementation and wanted multiple tests to use this format, I have written tests in this json format.

```
{
  "WebTestDefinition": [
    {
      "Name": "basic-portal03",
      "Kind": "ping",
      "GeoLocation":"us-ca-sjc-azr",
      "Tag": {
        "Key": "hidden-link:/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/azpwsh-rg-test/providers/microsoft.insights/components/appinsights-portal01",
        "Value": "Resource"
      },
      "Configuration": "<WebTest  Name=\"basic-portal03\"  Id=\"9407db10-5d84-487f-98a3-a1ee67bb98f0\"  Enabled=\"True\"  CssProjectStructure=\"\"  CssIteration=\"\"  Timeout=\"90\"  WorkItemIds=\"\"  xmlns=\"http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010\"  Description=\"\"  CredentialUserName=\"\"  CredentialPassword=\"\"  PreAuthenticate=\"True\"  Proxy=\"default\"  StopOnError=\"False\"  RecordedResultFile=\"\"  ResultsLocale=\"\"> 
    <Items> 
        <Request Method=\"GET\"  Guid=\"a2025e53-0702-d03e-f311-5774ec16893d\"  Version=\"1.1\"  Url=\"https://www.bing.com\"  ThinkTime=\"0\"  Timeout=\"90\"  ParseDependentRequests=\"True\"  FollowRedirects=\"True\"  RecordResult=\"True\"  Cache=\"False\"  ResponseTimeGoal=\"0\"  Encoding=\"utf-8\"  ExpectedHttpStatusCode=\"200\"  ExpectedResponseUrl=\"\"  ReportingName=\"\"  IgnoreHttpStatusCode=\"False\" /> 
    </Items> 
    <ValidationRules> 
        <ValidationRule  Classname=\"Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.Rules.ValidationRuleFindText, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a\"  DisplayName=\"Find Text\"  Description=\"Verifies the existence of the specified text in the response.\"  Level=\"High\"  ExectuionOrder=\"BeforeDependents\">
            <RuleParameters> 
            <RuleParameter Name=\"FindText\" Value=\"test content match\" /> 
            <RuleParameter Name=\"IgnoreCase\" Value=\"False\" /> 
            <RuleParameter Name=\"UseRegularExpression\" Value=\"False\" /> 
            <RuleParameter Name=\"PassIfTextFound\" Value=\"True\" /> 
            </RuleParameters> 
        </ValidationRule> 
    </ValidationRules> 
</WebTest>",
    }
  ]
}
```

And call a powershell script from .yml, passing variables and test name(e.g., name of the above json test file).

```
 - template: Deploy-WebTests.yml
    parameters:
      subscription: '${{ parameters.azureSubscriptionName }}'  
      WebTest: 'basic-portal03'
```

In powershell file, call the New-AzApplicationInsightsWebTest cmdlet.

```
$geoLocation = @()
$geoLocation =   $geoLocation += New-AzApplicationInsightsWebTestGeolocationObject -Location $($WebTestDef.GeoLocation) 
     New-AzApplicationInsightsWebTest -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $($WebTestDef.Name) -TestName $($WebTestDef.Name)  -Location 'westus2' `
        -GeoLocation $geoLocation -Tag @{$($WebTestDef.Tag.Key) = $($WebTestDef.Tag.Value)} -RetryEnabled -Enabled -Frequency 300 -Timeout 90 `
        -Kind $($WebTestDef.Kind) -Configuration $($WebTestDef.Configuration)
```